# double buffering and paint

Tags: java, swing, mouseevent, double-buffering

I'm using both double buffering and Swing Events which seem to conflict.  I'm using a JSlider and trying to double buffer.  It actually does the double buffering draw, but the double buffering gets painted again and I lose my image.  I'm using a JSlider to do the double buffering draw, and the event system seems to re-draw the frame (with 2 components, an image and the slider).  How do I do this the right way?  I've tried setting a repaint variable to signal not to repaint in the component but this does not work.  Is there some sort of event switch to stop repainting of certain components?  Should I not use double buffering?
Here's a code snippet.

```
private void drawOneByOne(ImageComponent imgComponent, JFrame f,
        MapObjects mapObjects, int number) {
    f.createBufferStrategy(2); 

    BufferStrategy bufferStrategy = f.getBufferStrategy();
    Graphics2D g = (Graphics2D)bufferStrategy.getDrawGraphics();            
    bufferStrategy = f.getBufferStrategy();
    g = (Graphics2D)bufferStrategy.getDrawGraphics();
    // draw the map and then the points
    imgComponent.paint(g);
    for (int i = 0; i < number; i++) {
        imgComponent.drawPoint(mapObjects.get(i),g);
    }
    imgComponent.repaint = false;
    bufferStrategy.show();
    g.dispose();
    imgComponent.repaint = true;
}
public void stateChanged(ChangeEvent e) {
    JSlider source = (JSlider)e.getSource();
    if (!source.getValueIsAdjusting()) {
        int voterNumber = source.getValue();
        System.out.println("Drawing One By One, " + voterNumber);
        drawOneByOne(this.imgComponent, this.f, this.mapObjects, voterNumber);
    }
}
```

.
.
.

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Answer (score 0):

Swing is [easily](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JComponent.html#setDoubleBuffered%28boolean%29) doublebuffered via `setDoubleBuffered(true)` if that is all you wanted to achieve. There is nothing wrong with double-buffering, it just uses more memory, call it on the parentcontainer of your swingcomponents. You have no control over the `repaint`, the OS calls it whenever it deems necessary unless you call [`setIgnoreRepaint`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/Component.html#setIgnoreRepaint%28boolean%29) on the JFrame.

Comment: I thought that it was set by default to be true for all JComponent children.

Comment: Swing components inherit double buffering from the parent container. Since by default the root pane is double buffered all components are double buffered.

Comment: My info is outdated then, should have known though, never noticed any flickering on swing components.